# Disabling CORS in Minimal API Ocelot Gateway

Tags: c#, cors, blazor-webassembly, ocelot, minimal-apis

So the problem is that i have Blazor WebAssembly for a front-end, Making API calls through the Ocelot API Gateway but for some reason the CORS are failing

[image]

but in `Ocelot Gateway` in `Program.cs` i have

```cpp
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange:true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();
await app.UseOcelot();

app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());

app.Run();
```

Having like this also does not work:

```cpp
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("asd",  
        policy =>  
        {  
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod();
        });  
});

var app = builder.Build();
await app.UseOcelot();
app.UseCors("asd");
app.Run();
```

What should I do to access any origin or just get rid of this cors? I have tried nearly everything but nothings seems to solve my problem.

Comment: can you provide your Program.cs file ?

Comment: Probably you should try placing `app.UseCors("asd");` before `await app.UseOcelot();`

Comment: Yes probably, I found the working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```cpp
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange:true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddCors(); // Add cors

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(builder => builder // Allow any
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());

await app.UseOcelot();
app.Run();
```